# Judgment for alternative words of "anticompetitive effects"

Tags: word-usage, difference

I am looking for some alternative words for "anticompetitive effects".

From the presidential actions of the President of US [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/07/09/executive-order-on-promoting-competition-in-the-american-economy/), I saw some words as below but I am not sure whether they can be used interchangeably with "anticompetitive effects"

- anticompetitive extension
- anticompetitive conduct
- anticompetitive distribution practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I've never heard "anticompetitive effects," although I can gloss its intended meaning. Something like [anti-competitive practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-competitive_practices) is a more established term. It appears to me that every use of "anticompetitive" there is just in reference to this term:

- Extensions (of whatever) that reduce market competition;
- Conduct that reduces market competition;
- Distribution practices that reduce market competition.

In other words, just adjectives being adjectival, nothing special about those terms.

Comment: So, do you mean, to some extent, these terms can be used interchangeably ?

Comment: They can't be used any more interchangeably than the unmodified nouns themselves can be. You wouldn't use "extension," "conduct," or "distribution practices" interchangeably, would you?

Comment: I got it, thanks @Feryll

Comment: a further question, is there any synonym for "anticompetitive practices" then? Can "anti-competitive conduct" be?

Comment: Maybe. Why in particular are you so interested in synonyms?

Comment: I am writing a academic paper and I try to paraphrase to some extents that would not bore the audience.

Comment: Ah. With established terms, though, especially in an academic context, you probably don't want to be changing words up just for flavor. If your sentence isn't just repeating old information, or using the same grammatical constructions ("Bob ran home. Bob ate lunch. Bob brushed his teeth.") your audience won't get bored.

Comment: Thanks a heap, Feryll :D